# Ассемблер в Linux

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, c++

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру! 
Возникла необходимость обучиться ассемблеру, а работать в Windows на старом хламе в универе не хочется, поэтому выбирают ноут с установленной Ubuntu 11.04. Подскажите пожалуйста какие пакеты мне необходимо установить для написания программ на ассеблере, а также как собирать и компилировать это проги из консоли? В дальнейшем планируется связать ассемблер с C++, что для этого нужно и какую литературу необходимо почитать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужны binutils. В них есть или as86/ld86, или gas (GNU Assembler). Особенностью ассемблера gas является использование AT&T синтаксиса. Т.е. это означает следующее:

- прямой порядок операндов (т.е. `src, dst`, а не наоборот, как на платформе Wintel);
- все инструкции ассемблера имеют суффикс, определяющий размер операндов. например, movb. Никаких ужасных конструкций вроде dword ptr как в TASM/MASM:-)
- другой (чем у MASM/TASM) формат адресации
- и многое другое

С другой стороны, этот синтаксис приближен к синтаксису ассемблера на нормальных, "больших" машинах.

В gcc, кстати, говоря используется именно AT&T синтаксис ассемблера, так что очень рекомендую его изучить.

Answer (score 4):

Самый популярный ассемблер для линукс - nasm. Ставится apt-get install nasm.
Книг по ассемблеру в линуксе мало. Хорошая книга по-английски Sivarama P. Dandamudi. Guide to Assembly Language Programming in Linux. Поищи в интернете. Там описано, как работать в насме, как компилировать, структура программы, синтаксис, а также общие теоретические понятия о работе с памятью, регистры процессора  и т.д.

Вот еще есть книга на русском Столяров А.В. Язык ассемблера в ОС Unix. Она есть в интернете на сайте автора в свободном доступе. Погугли.

Comment: А отладчик какой можете посоветовать?

Comment: gdb

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант есть возможность использовать встроенный ассемблер GCC. Пример

```
int main() {
    char *message = "Hello, world!\n";

    __asm__("\
        movl $4, %%eax\n\
        movl $0, %%ebx\n\
        push %0\n\
        pop %%ecx\n\
        movl $13,%%edx\n\
        int $0x80" : :"g"(message)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

И результат

```
gcc message.c && ./a.out
```

> `Hello, world!`

- [Linux Assembly HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Assembly-HOWTO/)
- [Using Assembly Language in Linux](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html)
- [Introduction to UNIX assembly programming](http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/Assembly-Intro.html)

Comment: Да, но все же лучше сначала освоить "самостоятельный" ассемблер, а уже потом переходить к встроенному.

Comment: Вариант очень хороший, обязательно изучу и его, но сначала основы

Comment: Весьма полезный вспомогательный инструмент для изучения ассемблера - gcc (да, Си компилятор) с ключом -S выводит ассемблерный код Си программы.

Comment: gcc -S генерирует код ассемблера в стиле GAS, т.е. с синтаксисом AT&T